# How can we make O365 addins run correctly in Citrix Non-persistent environments?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, citrix

We have an outlook O365 addin (Javascript) that works well in almost all environments including persistent Citrix environments.

For non-persistent (Citrix) environments though, our Javascript addin fails to load. When we reviewed the https-transactions, we saw a 'possible' CORS related issue in one of the HTTP-requests. Of course this issue does not happen in other environments. According to the data, the addin loading fails in the pre-flight (Options) call, with the server returning an error message of "Insufficient information. Origin request header needed".

As a test, we tried to install Slack Outlook addin. And the same issue was found. Unfortunately we were unable to see the http transactions for this addin.

Has anybody had any success in setting up Javascript addins in non-persistent Citrix environments? Any suggestions as to how we can install/setup these addins correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We are not familiar with the Citrix environment, but specifically which HTTP request is failing? Also, is this for Outlook in Windows, or is this Outlook on the web?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT we seem to have resolved this issue. I am posting the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by a corrupted installation of  Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost. The following resolution found in Outlook-JS github resolved the problem :

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1618